# Use setTimeout to postpone time intensive processing while data entry taking place

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I have a textarea that the user keys in some data.  I need to read this data when it is changed and process it, the processing is very time consuming.

I have the textarea events: change keyup cut paste input call the function triggerProcess().

If one character only is typed into the textarea (or one character only is deleted) then needs to be get called triggerProcess().

If a word of several characters is typed in then the whole system grinds to a halt if triggerProcess() gets called for every character in that word.  Even if the system did not grind to a halt it is pointless having triggerProcess() called for each character as the whole word plus the entire contents is what is required to be processed.  However a single character such as "I", or a number may need to be processed.

I want to postpone the processing if the typist is typing a word or sentence (if the typist is fast ) but once they pause then their data is processed.

As soon as triggerProcess is called the first thing it does is clear a timer and then set another timer that calls the intensive processing when it expires.
My idea is to put a short timeout in triggerProcess of about 300ms so that there is always at least 300ms before the data is read from the textarea and processed.  If one character say "I" is typed then that will be processed, but if several characters are typed in a sequence such as when a word is typed then triggerProcess is called by the textarea event watchers, the timer is cleared and started again for each character.  When the word is finished and there is a gap in the stream from the keyboard into the text area the last started timer expires and the word is processed.  I know that this will freeze the typist out while the text area contents is being processed, but that freeze out is much better than having the typist frozen out for each character.

How does my code look?  Could something go terribly wrong? Could it be improved?

Thank you for taking the time to read this, all comments gratefully received.

Peter

```
var delayTimer;  //global variable as opposed to local variable so that it can be cleared within function display.
function triggerProcess(){
   clearTimeout(delayTimer);
   delayTimer = 0;
   delayTimer=setTimeout(function(){
      // when the Timeout fires then
     // read the data from the textarea and have some very time consuming work on it 
   },300);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called `autocomplete`.

Your code looks cool to me, but If I were you, I will not go for setTimeOut because that is a hack and will make the experience slow. I would think of **AJAX** call rather than a `setTimeOut` With **AJAX** (since the call is asynchronous), you can send request as many times as you want without user experiencing anything bad. Whenever the user types and change event will be called, it will ask for new matching words and will show the new matching words to user, when it has any.

I do not know if you use jQuery or not, but anyhow jQuery UI has one component (See here [jQuery UI AUtocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)). Since thank god jQuery UI is an open-source project, you can see the code at /ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js. If you open the other autocompleteEvents.js, you can see that there are four event types there: focus, close, select, change. As you can see in [autocomplete example](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/9470af0bbefafa3d81c3709674a45a54b693e7cf/demos/autocomplete/xml.html).

```
           $.ajax({
                    //Where you load the data, could be a backend server instead of a
                    // XML  file
                    url: "london.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function( xmlResponse ) {
                             //If matching any element from the london.xml file,
                             // Show the result in a menu or something
                    }
            });
```

It is just calling whenever anything gets changed to get the new results (as simple as that). If you do not like AJAX, try to use callbacks, show the results after you sent the newly typed word and get a reply back and not in between.

Here is just another autocomplete example with my second suggestion in mind: [complete.ly](http://complete-ly.appspot.com/). It shares the same concept.
It just adds the onchange and keyup event:

```
     if (txt.addEventListener) {
        txt.addEventListener("input",  handler, false);
        txt.addEventListener('keyup',  handler, false);
        txt.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
    }
```

And will make the callback whenever it is done with getting new values, checking if anything matches and will show the result:

```
    var handler = function() {
        var value = txt.value;
        if (registerOnTextChangeOldValue !== value) {
            callback(value);
        }
    };
```

Read the full source here: [complete.ly source code](http://lorenzoongithub.github.io/completely/complete.ly.1.0.1.js)
I hope I make sense and my answer helped!

Comment: Thank you Ambodi.  I have very limited exposure to AJAX jQuery but now that I have studied your suggestion and I am in a much better position now.  I also searched under "Autocomplete" and found a wealth of info.  I had not thought this as and autocomplete applicatio.  My application is not an autocomplete, but it has much in common with autocomplete. Thanks, Peter